# Touchpad zig-zag in linux

Tags: ubuntu, touchpad

I have the issue that when I'm moving my finger diagonal on my touchpad, it tends to make a zig-zag pattern when I go slow. 
Also when I want to move the cursor, a few pixel over to a link, it doesn't react until I move my finger enough and then it makes a jump, making it hard to hit links.

I've tried to draw the pattern in kolourpaint https://i.stack.imgur.com/XU998.png

This is done with a MSI GE60 2PC-Apache

Comment: Using the touchpad for things that need fine-grained movements doesn't sound like a good idea. You could try to decrease the mouse movement speed. Or you could try to use one of those pens designed for smart phones.